# Calling python method from java script self is null in odoo 12

Tags: javascript, python, odoo

I have one method if I am calling this python method on the button from XML as below:

```
<button id="button_update_question" name="testquestion1" type="object" string="Update Question" class="oe_highlight" />
```

Gives me self as : **self: survey.survey(1,)**

If I am trying to call this same python method from javascript as:

```
this._rpc({
                    model: 'survey.survey',
                    method: 'testquestion1',
                    args: [{
                        id: id,
                        question: question,
                        type: type,
                    }],  
         });
```

It gives me self as: **self: survey.survey()**

**My question** is that Why self doesn’t have any vale if calling the python method from javascript. How to achieve this. Please, anyone, help me

Thanks in advance.

**Update**
Signature for testquestion1:

```
  @api.multi
    def testquestion1(self,vals):
       print('self:',self)
        id1 = vals['id']        
        type_val = vals['type']  
        update_data = {}
        update_data = {
            'question': vals['question'],
        }
        exiting_data = self.env['survey.question'].search([('id','=',id1)]).write(update_data)
```

Comment: Can you show the `testquestion1` signature?

Comment: Thanks @Kenly For your replay. I have updated the question and add a testquestion1 signature can you please check.

Answer (score 1):

Try to pass `ids` to the `testquestion1` method.

```
this._rpc({
    model: 'survey.survey',
    method: 'testquestion1',
    args: [event.data.record.res_ids,
    {
        id: id,
        question: question,
        type: type,
    }],
});
```